# Spyder Editor does not show the right colour text - how do I correct this?

Tags: syntax, colors, spyder

In Spyder, I have gone into preferences and changed the syntax colour scheme to Monokai. Originally, this updated both the Editor and Console as intended.

After not using Spyder for a few days, now only the Console shows the correct colour scheme. The Editor is black, but all code is grey. This is a nuisance.

I've tried changing the scheme to another scheme. E.g. back to Spyder's default scheme. The Editor background changes to white, but all code is black. The console shows the right colours.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[Spyder_Colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrDEN.jpg)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If you're not seeing syntax highlighting in the Editor is because your file doesn't end with the `.py` extension.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem.

Comment: Ok, glad to know. I'll add it as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) If you're not seeing syntax highlighting in the Editor is because your file doesn't end with the `.py` extension.